# Nothing is being added to my output list. Can anyone explain why

Tags: python, komodo

```
  def translateGene(dnaStrand, startPos, stop):
        protein = []
        def aminoAcid(dnaCodon):
            return(dnaCode[dnaCodon])
            maybeCodon = [dnaStrand[i:i +3] for i in range (startPos, stop-1)]
            for j in maybeCodon:
                if j == (dnaCode[dnaCodon]):
                    protein.append(j)
                return protein
```

This function takes a string, an integer as a starting index in the string and an integer as an ending index in the string. The idea of the program is to split the string into 3 letter acronyms with the letters from the starting point to the endpoint. Then it should look up a given dictionary for all the acronyms and if they are present in the dictionary, add their results to the protein list but my code above leaves protein empty. The function Aminoacid has been created for me to use as part of this function, but I'm not sure if I've called it correctly. My code above leaves protein empty.

Can anyone explain why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you have nested functions and you're never calling ``aminoAcid`` - and even if you did, you'd return immediately, before ``protein.append(j)`` is called.

Comment: There is a `return` in `def aminoAcid(...)` before anything happens. Function will exit there. Nevertheless it will never be called (except you just made an indention error here in your post and some code is missing).

Comment: it looks to me like aminoAcid() is defined but never called.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your input and expected output, please?

Comment: Yeah sure, something like this: translateGene('GGGATGCTTTAG', 3, 9)  The program should then break the string down between index 3 and 9 to give three-letter acronyms starting at the next letter along each time for example in the string above, the acronyms would be: ATG, TGC, GCT, CTT. Some of these acronyms are stored in a dictionary called dnaCode, the idea is that each acronym is checked against the dictionary and if they are present the corresponding Aminoacid would go into the protein list, in this case  'ATG' : 'Met and 'CTT ': 'Leu'  therefore Met and Leu should be in the protein list.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that your code should be indenting adjusted to:

```
def translateGene(dnaStrand, startPos, stop):
    protein = []
    
    def aminoAcid(dnaCodon):
        return (dnaCode[dnaCodon])
    
    maybeCodon = [dnaStrand[i:i + 3] for i in range(startPos, stop - 1)]
    for j in maybeCodon:
        if j == (dnaCode[dnaCodon]):
            protein.append(dnaCodon)
    return protein
```

Then test it.

and notice  that, It seems that you have two global `dnaCode`,`dnCodon`, which is known before calling the function.